# How to save matlab result and use it in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I was wondering how can i save the result from a matlab function and use it in VB.net (if not possible then save the result in a .txt file and then use it in VB.net). thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you can save to a text file can be used in vb.net. See System.IO. There seems to be several links for interop with .net an matlab.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i save the value of the variable in .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB can be linked by many software such HSPICE, ANSYS , ...

There are special toolbox for these software , But I do not know ant toolbox for VB.

A simple solution is the save your result in text file.

Text file can be read in any programming language.

A important note in saving, pay attention to encoding. Source and Destination encoding must be same.

Comment: 'save('myFile.txt', 'excel', '-ASCII','-append');' myFile is name of your file

Comment: Ok sorry but i got this error: Error using save
Variable 'excel' not found.

Error in dele (line 13)
save('r1.txt', 'excel', '-ASCII','-append');                                                                         ok i'll be more specific i have this .m file and i want to save the value of I to use it in VB.net:                                                                                                                              fid = fopen('RT1.DAT','rb');
y = fread(fid,'uint8=>double');
y = (mean(y(1:2:end) )+ i*y(2:2:end));
I = real(y);
Q = imag(y);

Comment: ohhh ok i just had to add the directory thank you so much.